# http POST Formatting Issue - As array, list?

Tags: java, android, http

I am attempting to make a "Freebusy" request to connect to Google Calendar API. Currently I am stuck on formatting the http POST. I am getting an error:

```
{
  "error": {
   "errors": [
    {
     "domain": "global",
     "reason": "parseError",
     "message": "Parse Error"
    }
   ],
   "code": 400,
   "message": "Parse Error"
  }
}
```

---

I am attempting to format the request like this:

```
{
  "timeMin": datetime,
  "timeMax": datetime,
  "timeZone": string,
  "groupExpansionMax": integer,
  "calendarExpansionMax": integer,
  "items": [
    {
      "id": string
    }
  ]
}
```

And am currently doing this to format it:

```
String[] stringPairs = new String[]{
            "timeMin",       date1,
            "timeMax",       date2,
            "items[]",       calendarID,
            "timezone",      "Canada/Toronto"};

//Create an HTTP post request
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("HostULR");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(stringPairs.length/2 - 1);

for (int i = 0; i < stringPairs.length; i += 2) {
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(stringPairs[i], stringPairs[i+1]));
}

post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
org.apache.http.HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

I believe the part I am screwing up on is the `"items"` part.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if this is correct for java but in C you just plug another json into it to make a complex json.

Maybe this website can you help you.

https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples#Example_1-3_-_Encode_a_JSON_object_-_Using_Map

Edit: I noticed that the form is an array of objects... So the correct implementation would be like this.

```
  JSONObject obj=new JSONObject();
  obj.put("ID", string);

  JSONArray list = new JSONArray();

  list.add(obj);

  JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject();{
            object.put("timeMin", date1)
            ....
```

Also, I don't know about this code...

```
"timezone",      "Canada/Toronto"}, accessToken );
```

With json objects it's generally {} symbolizes json objects [] these are arrays.

EDIT 2:
After creating the JSON do this

```
StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(json.toString());
                     entity.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
                     entity.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json;charset=UTF-8"));
                     request.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
                     request.setEntity(entity); 

                     HttpResponse response =null;
                     DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                     HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpClient.getParams(), Constants.ANDROID_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT*1000); 
                     HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpClient.getParams(),Constants.ANDROID_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT*1000); 
                     try{

                     response = httpClient.execute(request); 
                     }
                     catch(SocketException se)
                     {
                         Log.e("SocketException", se+"");
                         throw se;
                     }




InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String line = null;
while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
    sb.append(line);
```

Comment: Hmm, this is getting closer, that's for sure. Not 100% that this will work though. I updated my question to simplify my code, and make it more clear what I am doing. I'll play around with your theory

Comment: I edited my post to include stuff  you should change also in your request settings also you need to include "Content Length." I'm not sure if java's http request does this for you. GL!

Comment: @progenhard: "Don't know if this is correct for java but in C you just plug another json into it to make a complex json." json is language independent, so yes, one could do that no matter on what programming language we are using.

Comment: your putting a `JSON list` into a `JSON Object` worked out. Thanks. Also, futur readers, make sure to include the `post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");`

Answer (score 0):

What about making a class that match the json you are trying to send and put an `ArrayList<String>` on it, then you use a Json parser like [Gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) and use a `StringEntity` for send the post request, here is an Example:

```
public class JsonTest extends AsyncTask<GoogleCalendarJson, Void, String> {
private HttpClient client;
private HttpPost request;
private HttpResponse response;
private Activity activity;

public JsonTest(Activity a){
    activity = a;
}

@Override
public String doInBackground(GoogleCalendarJson... object){
    client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    request = new HttpPost("YOUR URL HERE");
    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer("");
    String json = new Gson().toJson(object[0]);
    InputStream is = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    try{
        StringEntity se = new StringEntity(json);
        request.setHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json");
        request.setEntity(se);
        response = client.execute(request);
        is = response.getEntity().getContent();
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        String line = null;
        while(((line = br.readLine()) != null)){
            b.append(line);
        }
        br.close();
    }catch(IOException e){
        b.append(e.getMessage());
    }

    return b.toString();
}
@Override
public void onPostExecute(final String result){
    activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run(){
            TextView t = (TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.result);
            t.setText(result);
        }
    });
}
}
```

`configuration` is a `plain old java object` and it didn't have reference to another `configuration` object, `configuration` could have an `ArrayList<String>`, I'm not sure if you could have an `ArrayList<Item>` on it you could try it, as a plus, one could use [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) instead of HttpClient of apache if you're programming for post-gingerbread app here is the `WHY` http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html,  hope this to be helpful to anyone.
PD: I didn't use an IDE for the code below, sorry if got errors (I don't have Android Studio @home by the moment, I formatted this code with netbeans :p).

EDIT: just for clarification, this AsyncTask should be run in the UI Thread (say in an Activity) like this:

```
JsonTest test = new JsonTest(this); //here we pass the Activity
test.execute(new GoogleCalendarJson()); //this is the object we get in 'object0]'
```

EDIT 2: new code is actually working perfectly let me put you the example of GoogleCalendarJson class:

GoogleCalendarJson class (must have getters/setters):

```
public class GoogleCalendarJson {
private String timeMin, timeMax, timezone;
private int groupExpanxionMaxm, calendarExpansionMax;
private ArrayList<Item> items;

public GoogleCalendarJson() {
}
}
```

Item class (same thing with g/s):

```
public class Item {
private String id;

public Item() {
}
}
```

Json Example Generated with Gson:

```
{"timezone":"someTimezone","timeMin":"min","items":
[{"id":"someID"}],"timeMax":"max","groupExpanxionMaxm":2,"calendarExpansionMax":1}
```

to check Json structure you could paste the json above in here [JsonValidator](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/)
for test this code you need an Activity that has at least a TextView with id:`result`